# React Native async execution

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'd like to execute some async function to fetch some data from db without freezing the UI. 
This is the code I wrote

```
export default class CustomComponent extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     value:0
   };
 }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchData().then(result => { this.setState(value:result);});
  }

  async fetchData() {    
    var appState = await someMethod()
    return appState;
  }

  someMethod() {
   return new Promise(resolve => {
         resolve(queryFromDB())
        });
  }

  queryFromDB() {
     // Returns a value fetched from Realm
     let events = this.realm.objects("Event");
     return events.length;
   }

  render() {
   return (
     <Text> {this.state.value} </Text> 
   );
  }
}
```

The problem is that it does execute on the main thread, freezing the app.

What's the error?

Comment: Please post the whole code of your db access. In the parts you've shown, you're not doing anything asynchronous.

Comment: How can you say that it runs on the main thread/freezes the app? I think you need to have render `if(this.state.result){ <ActivityIndicator /> }` to have something on the page while the fetch executes

Comment: Notice that all asynchronous code is executed on the main thread in JavaScript. It's the background tasks which the async code does wait for that execute concurrently.

Comment: @Bergi I edited the question, this is the component code

Comment: @mjabadilla I edited the question. I say it freezes because I cannot switch tabs or click any other component until the value (in the code) is returned from db

Comment: @r4id4 your `queryFromDB`, where the interesting stuff happens, still just contains a comment.

Comment: @Bergi, updated, sorry :D

Comment: Adding a preloader is the best option!

Comment: `someMethod` does not execute the code async from `queryFromDB`. afaik, the function param of `new Promise` is executed immediately. I may be wrong though.

Comment: `return new Promise(resolve => { resolve(queryFromDB())  })` just wrapping your code into a promise doesnt make it async.

Comment: @JonasW. how should it be done? I'm new to js, I was following this tutorial https://www.dalejefferson.com/es7-async-await-with-react-native/ , but clearly it's a simpler use case than mine

Comment: And whats your usecase?

Comment: @JonasW. I need to query a database, he's returning a constant value.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your code has syntax errors. You have written all your code inside the constructor. Try this.

```
export default class CustomComponent extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     value:0
   };
 }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchData().then(result => { this.setState(value:result);});
  }

  async fetchData() {    
    var appState = await someMethod()
    return appState;
  }

  someMethod() {
   return new Promise(resolve => {
         resolve(queryFromDB())
        });
  }

  queryFromDB() {
     // Returns a value fetched from Realm
     let events = this.realm.objects("Event");
     return events.length;
   }

  render() {
   return (
     <Text> {this.state.value} </Text> 
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the edit, I just cut and pasted forgetting some brackets :D